# how to keep value constant for every run?

Tags: java, jvm

Using java I want to generate some random values in one program and then use these values in some other program everytime the 2nd program is executed.

Purpose of this is to generate random values once and then hold and keep them constant for every run of the program later. Is it possible in some way? Thanks

Comment: Oli i dont want to use any external I/O. is there anyway within jvm memory or some other way to do it without stroing it in a file

Comment: Relevant XKCD - http://xkcd.com/221/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you exit a program, anything you don't store in a file is lost.

I suspect you don't need to worry about IO as much as you think.  You should be able to read millions of values in a few milli-seconds.  In fact you should be able to generate millions of random numbers in a fraction of a second.

```
Random random = new Random(1);
long start = System.nanoTime();
int values = 1000000;
for (int i = 0; i < values; i++)
    random.nextInt();
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to generate %,d values%n",
                  time / 1e9, values);
```

prints

```
Took 0.015 seconds to generate 1,000,000 values
```

---

Generating and writing

```
int values = 1000000;
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(4 * values).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());

Random random = new Random(1);
long start = System.nanoTime();
for (int i = 0; i < values; i++)
    buffer.putInt(random.nextInt());
buffer.flip();
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/tmp/random.ints");
fos.getChannel().write(buffer);
fos.close();
long time = System.nanoTime() - start;
System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to generate&write %,d values%n", time / 1e9, values);
```

prints

```
Took 0.021 seconds to generate&write 1,000,000 values
```

---

Reading the same file.

```
long start2 = System.nanoTime();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("/tmp/random.ints");
MappedByteBuffer buffer2 = fis.getChannel().map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_ONLY, 0, values * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
for (int i = 0; i < values; i++)
    buffer2.getInt();
fis.close();
long time2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;
System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to read %,d values%n", time2 / 1e9, values);
```

prints

```
Took 0.011 seconds to read 1,000,000 values
```

---

Reading the same file repeatedly

```
long sum = 0;
int repeats = 1000;
for (int j = 0; j < repeats; j++) {
    buffer2.position(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < values; i++)
        sum += buffer2.getInt();
}
fis.close();
long time2 = System.nanoTime() - start2;
System.out.printf("Took %.3f seconds to read %,d values%n", time2 / 1e9, repeats * values);
```

prints

```
Took 1.833 seconds to read 1,000,000,000 values
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation with examples.But infact I needed this for Java user defined functions for teradata. So consider if we need to generate 5 million records and then run the function for all those 5 million records. so generating 5 million records for 5 million time will cost me seconds also in millions which means hours of extra time.

Comment: That is true, but whatever you do 5 million times 5 millions times is going to take a long time.  I suspect there is a different way to solve the problem so you don't need to do this.

Comment: Reading the file the first time takes most of the time. Each access is only taking 1.8 nano-seconds which is just a few clock cycles.  I doubt you will get it much faster than that and still do something useful.

Comment: If you do something 25 trillion times, every 3.8 ns each thing takes (about 10 clock cycles) will add one day to the total. :P

Answer (score 3):

a couple of ways you may consider to go

1 using the same seed to generate random number

2 generate the random and save them in a file. your program two reads the file to get values.

Comment: Kent I want to generate random number once as it might be used for millions of time later so generating random numbers everytime will increase the time considerable and dont want to write it in a file because of same time factor

Comment: how many numbers do you want to generate, are they this big to take much time to be written in a file? The second issue, is when you load them from hte file you will load them into local variables, not each time you need them you will laod them, which won't take time either. I used to do so using matlab, it didn't took many time.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest way is to run the program once, note down the random numbers generated, and then hardcode the random numbers in an array in your program! Then, the next time onwards, your program can read these same values from the array.

So suppose you program generates random numbers as follows -

0.34, 0.15, 0.28, 0.45, ...

You can then define an array and store these values in it.

```
  randomValues[0] = 0.34;
  randomValues[1] = 0.15;
  randomValues[2] = 0.28; 
  randomValues[3] = 0.45;
  .
  .
  .
```

Then each time, simply use an index to get the random number you want.

```
 index = 0; 
 randomNumber = randomValues[index];
 index++; // so the next time, you can get the next random number in sequence.
```

Answer (score 0):

Generate them once, then save them into a file...
afterthat, everytime you want to run your program, you have to load these values again.